# <command-line>: error : in makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to compile a large number of files using the make utility. In between the run I get the following error many times

```
<command-line>: error: macro names must be identifiers
```

Since I am using the -j option the log shows output from random threads. So the actual file where this error is encountered is very difficult to determined. Also no other errors pop up. Can somebody please tell me what actually this error is trying to indicate ?

Comment: What's the line that caused the error? :)

Comment: Actually jobs are getting done in parallel, so from the output log it is not possible to figure out what line is causing this to occur. May be if I can know what this error actually means in context of makefiles I can figure out why it is showing up

Answer (score 3):

This is from the C preprocessor.  It generally happens when you pass a -D switch to gcc with an invalid symbol or no symbol at all.

The root cause is probably a line in your makefile like

```
CFLAGS=-g -D$(DEBUG)
```

or something like that, where DEBUG isn't actually defined anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error message from `make`, but from the preprocessor (which is invoked by `make`).
As others have said, run `make` without the `-j` option (either from the start, or after `make -j` has failed) to get a clearer view of where the error originates.

Answer (score 0):

Not all `Makefile`s are ready for compilation with `-j`. Sometimes you just have to run `make -j` several times before the project will build all the way to the end. And you can always take off the `-j` once it does throw a failure, and try finishing the build with a single process in flight at any time. This can immensely cut down on unpredictability when trying to debug something, while still using parallel build jobs for some (or almost all, if you're lucky) of the compiles.

I'm having trouble tracking down what constitutes an identifier in `make(1)`, but in most languages, restrictions are usually along the lines of: "first character must be [a-zA-Z], all other characters must be [a-zA-Z0-9_]". I imagine `make(1)`'s rules are similar.